# Visual Studio 2022, respect on purpose tabs

Tags: tabs, indentation, visual-studio-2022, spacing

I would like to respect this kind of tabs

```
var hash = new HashSet<int>();
    hash.Add(1);
    hash.Add(2);
```

Instead When I end a block o anything else, the code goes back to

```
var hash = new HashSet<int>();
hash.Add(1);
hash.Add(2);
```

Anyone know an option for this? I was able to do it in a previous version of Visual Studio, so I know it is possible.
Thank you.